# Invoke Makefile in different directory without exiting Vim

Tags: vim, makefile

Referring to the structure below, suppose that I am in `/test` directory and I opened `vim main.cpp`. Running `:make` would invoke `/test/Makefile`. Now I do `:edit ../src/foo.cpp` and made changes here, too. I want to run `make` on `/Makefile` to create a shared library in `/lib`. How can I run `make` on `/Makefile` without exiting Vim?

```
project
|  Makefile
|+ lib
|+ include
|- src
    |  foo.cpp
|- test
    |  main.cpp
    |  Makefile
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just run:

```
:make -C path_to_dir_with_your_makefile
```

Where `-C`:

```
-C dir, --directory=dir
        Change to directory dir before reading the makefiles or doing anything else.  If multiple -C options are specified, each is interpreted relative to the previous one: -C / -C etc  is
        equivalent to -C /etc.  This is typically used with recursive invocations of make.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
 :lcd ..
```

Which will change the local directory (for the current window only).
If you want to change the directory for all your windows, use:

```
:cd directory/
```

Then you can use `:make` as usual.

Comment: To change the path for all windows you can do `:windo lcd {path}` as well